# Can you print a random number generated (10 integer) One-Dimensional Array Vertically?

Tags: java

I have to display this random number generated array for class both vertically and horizontally. This is what I have so far...

```
public class chapterEightHW {
    // Global Scanner/Array/RandomGenerator
    private static final Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static int[] array = new int[10];
    private static int SecureRandom generator = new SecureRandom();
```

```
 // Initialize Array
    public static void initializeArray() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // initialize Array
            array[i] = 10 + generator.nextInt(99);
        }
    }

    // Display Array Horizontally with space betweeen #'s
    public static int displayArrayHoriz() {
        System.out.printf("%s%n%n", Arrays.toString(array)); // display array
    }

    // Display Array Vertically
    public static int displayArrayVert() {
       System.out.println(array[0]);
       System.out.println(array[1]);
       System.out.println(array[2]);
       System.out.println(array[3]);
       System.out.println(array[4]);
       System.out.println(array[5]);
       System.out.println(array[6]);
       System.out.println(array[7]);
       System.out.println(array[8]);
       System.out.println(array[9]);
    }
```

Is there at better way to display the vertical version of the array other than 10 print statements?

Comment: Use a for loop like you did in the initializeArray method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         System.out.println(array[i]);
    }
```

Alternatively, you could iterate through the array and build a string using StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         str.append(array[i] + "\n");
    }
System.out.println(str.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [for each loop](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/foreach.html) since you only need the value and not the index.

```
for(int x: array) {
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

You could also use a `Stream`.

```
java.util.Arrays.stream(array).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a for loop to print through the array elements the same exact way you initialized the array; in fact, you can even do it in the same for loop you made earlier.

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { // initialize Array
            array[i] = 10 + generator.nextInt(99);
            System.out.println(array[i]); // prints out array element right after it is initialized
        }
```